# ID column based on condition in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Hej,
I have the following column A which shows continuous data sampling. If the value changes the Sensor is measuring data, if the values repeat itself the sensor is not measuring actual values.
`
I would like to loop through A and assign an ID column with the condition that if the measurement starts and the values are changing continuously the ID should be the same. If the values are not changing the ID should increment by one. If then the values start changing again another increment should be added to the ID column and so forth.
Tried this so far which does not accurately assigns the ID

```
import pandas as pd


data = [3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3.9, 4.0, 4.2, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 3,        
3, 3,  3, 3.2, 3.3, 3.5, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': data})

# Initialize ID 
df['ID'] = 0

# Assign ID
 id_value = 1
 for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.at[i, 'A'] != df.at[i-1, 'A']:
       df.at[i, 'ID'] = df.at[i-1, 'ID']
    else:
       df.at[i, 'ID'] = id_value
       id_value += 1

print(df)


Expected output:
      A  ID
 0   3.5   0
 1   3.6   0
 2   3.7   0
 3   3.8   0
 4   1.0   1
 5   1.0   1
 6   1.0   1
 7   1.0   1
 8   1.0   1
 9   3.9   2
 10  4.0   2
```

…

In my output the data is incremented continuously, so each row has its own ID.

Comment: You say "does not accurately assigns the ID" but don't show what is wrong with the result. Pleas show the output and explain what should be different.

Comment: Please post expected output

Comment: Is that one row which contains a list as the value, or multiple rows? If each value is on a separate row, you shouldn't have `[]` around it.

Comment: It's like an inverse groupby. This should be an interesting one to solve.

Comment: if I follow the logic, should the row with the first 1.0 be part of group 0 as the numbers from index 0 to 4 are still changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the expected output is correct you can do this by looking at the value of the previous AND the next row using shift. Assigning the result to a new column so we can make use the cumulative sum against it.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': data})
>>> df['Changing'] = (df['A'] != df['A'].shift(-1)) & (df['A'] != df['A'].shift())
>>> df
      A  Changing
0   3.5      True
1   3.6      True
2   3.7      True
3   3.8      True
4   1.0     False
5   1.0     False
6   1.0     False
7   1.0     False
8   1.0     False
9   3.9      True
10  4.0      True
11  4.2      True
12  4.4      True
13  4.6      True
14  4.8      True
15  3.0     False
16  3.0     False
17  3.0     False
18  3.0     False
19  3.2      True
20  3.3      True
21  3.5      True
22  2.1     False
23  2.1     False
24  2.1     False
25  2.1     False
>>> df['ID'] = (df['Changing'] != df['Changing'].shift()).cumsum() - 1
>>> df
      A  Changing  ID
0   3.5      True   0
1   3.6      True   0
2   3.7      True   0
3   3.8      True   0
4   1.0     False   1
5   1.0     False   1
6   1.0     False   1
7   1.0     False   1
8   1.0     False   1
9   3.9      True   2
10  4.0      True   2
11  4.2      True   2
12  4.4      True   2
13  4.6      True   2
14  4.8      True   2
15  3.0     False   3
16  3.0     False   3
17  3.0     False   3
18  3.0     False   3
19  3.2      True   4
20  3.3      True   4
21  3.5      True   4
22  2.1     False   5
23  2.1     False   5
24  2.1     False   5
25  2.1     False   5
```

I subtracted 1 from the cumsum to follow the expected output. You can then drop the added column as needed.

Answer (score 0):

After several fails, I managed to get the output you wanted

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3.9, 4.0, 4.2, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3.2, 3.3, 3.5, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': data})

# Initialize ID
df['ID'] = 0

# Assign ID
id_value = 0
prev_value = df.at[0, 'A']
value_was_changing = True

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    value_is_changing = df.at[i, 'A'] != prev_value
    if value_is_changing:
        if not value_was_changing:
            id_value += 1
    else:
        if value_was_changing:
            id_value += 1
    
    df.at[i, 'ID'] = id_value
    prev_value = df.at[i, 'A']
    value_was_changing = value_is_changing

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      A  ID
0   3.5   0
1   3.6   0
2   3.7   0
3   3.8   0
4   1.0   0
5   1.0   1
6   1.0   1
7   1.0   1
8   1.0   1
9   3.9   2
10  4.0   2
11  4.2   2
12  4.4   2
13  4.6   2
14  4.8   2
15  3.0   2
16  3.0   3
17  3.0   3
18  3.0   3
19  3.2   4
20  3.3   4
21  3.5   4
22  2.1   4
23  2.1   5
24  2.1   5
25  2.1   5
```

**Explanation**

I edited the script to accurately track whether the values are continuously changing or staying the same, and assign IDs accordingly.

1. Added `prev_value` variable to keep track of the previous value in the loop
2. Added `value_was_changing` flag to keep track of whether the previous value was changing or not.
3. Added `value_is_changing` to determine if the current value is different from the previous value.
4. The loop increments `id_value` when there's a transition between changing and not changing states.
5. Updated `prev_value` and `value_was_changing` at the end of each iteration for use in the next iteration.